# finding the defect button

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-preprocessing, image-segmentation

In case of a project where you are going to detect whether the image printed on a button is correct or not and given that you have only a one correct possibility of a correct image and some incorrect ones, do I need deep learning for such a project ?
If yes what type of problem do you classify it?
(should I use image segmentation? Does image segmentation work when you have letters printed on buttons?)

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. It sounds like your problem is binary classification, but your explanation is not very clear.

Comment: Thank you @Erwan for responding!
The task is defining if a button is defect or not.
I have various types of buttons.
A button is called a defect button if the image printed on it is not 100% correct.
Every button has its own dataset.
The dataset is composed of 2 folders: one called non defective and contains only a one image
and the other one contains dozen of images that are defective.
If it is a binary classification, I should then have various examples of non defective button whereas I only have a one. Am I wrong?

Comment: You must have a representative sample of your data. Normally one sample is not enough for training a good classifier. The standard way to have a representative sample is to take a random sample from whatever is the source of these images, and then annotate the images as defective or not. Respecting the original proportion between the classes defect/no defect is important, otherwise the classifier won't work properly.

Comment: I think I cannot use data augmentation for such a case (because as I have found, the data augmentation consists in rotating, rescaling .. an image or here I should have the exact image).  What do you think about using semantic segmentation. I've just read a little about it and thought of using it to compare segmented images (the correct image and the tested one). Thank you so much @Erwan for your time!

Comment: I know very little about images classification so I'm not the right person to answer any specific technical question. But from the point of view of general ML principles it seems very strange to proceed with a training set built like this: assuming that the goal is to use the classifier later with some real input images "in production", it's likely to make a lot of errors if either the class proportion or diversity of images is very different from the training set.

Comment: It was also my point of view! I didn't see any use for deep learning here, but the subject of the project does force to use deep learning.